# Load a php-page in a div without loading div before mysql is ready

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Everything works, but what ever I do the list sometimes "reloads" with the deleted row (not allways). Is it too fast or is it cached somehow? When I refresh the page I can see that the row is deleted, but how can I prevent the list to show before the list is updated?

It doesn´t matter if i use load or post and include the posted variables in the loaded file or in a separate one and then load the file, still the same problem. If I add an alert in the function then it always works fine, so that´s why I think it is too fast.

I have also tried to "unset" the link to partlist.php and then get it from the database in the function but it still doesn´t always show the updated version until I refresh the page, thats why I suspect a cached version.

**The script:**

```
$(".taBort").click(function(){  

    var r = confirm("Do you want to delete the row?");
    if (r == true) {

        var taBortid= $(this).val();

        $.post("delete.php", {

            taBortRad:  "Ta bort",          
            taBortid:   taBortid
            success:    function (data) {

                lista();

            }

        });

    }

});
```

**The php file where I handle all my updates for this page:**

```
if(isset($_POST['taBortRad'])){

    $taBortid=$_POST['taBortid'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM parts WHERE id='$taBortid'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

}
```

**And the function that loads the php-file where the partlist is in the "lista" div**

```
function lista(edit){

    $("#lista").load(partlist.php,{

        edit: edit //Just a variable I use, not active here

    });

}
```

Comment: A side issue: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Anyway rather than refreshing your whole list from the server, why not just use a little bit of javascript to remove the just-deleted row from the page?

Comment: This is just a small example, I have more complex updates that changes a lot of things so I´d rather reload the table. Some of them also changes order in the list. That´s why. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Well the code looks like it should work in the correct order, so it's hard to say. What kind of button or element is selected by ".taBort"? It's not a "submit" button by any chance (e.g. `<input type="submit"` or `<button` (with no "type", meaning "submit" is the default)? If it's then within a `<form` tag, that would cause a full page postback at the same time, which, if you hadn't noticed it, could explain the apparent discrepancy since the delete might not complete before that has executed.

Comment: If it's not that, then caching is potentially an issue, yes. You can specify `cache:false` as an ajax option to prevent requesting a cached version (although you'd have to use $.get() or $.ajax() instead of $.load() in order to send the option), or you can look at your webserver config to see if it's possible to disable server-side caching for the script which sends the table data. Also check if the browser is caching the data somehow (as opposed to the server).

Comment: <button class="taBort button-edit" value="'.$delid.'"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>

Comment: yep that's a "submit" button because that's it's default behaviour. It could well be posting back your page. Try with `<button type="button"`... instead

Comment: Tried it, same problem. :(

Comment: ok well it's worth leaving in there for clarity anyway. Next thing to try is the cache: false stuff

Comment: And for that I need to use get or ajax instead then?

Comment: yes because $.load is meant to be really simple, and doesn't allow you to pass any custom options. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ does (see the second overload).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, delete.php is deleting the row and partList.php what is doing?
I think that you must use a promise, a deferred object in this way and in php you must use a discriminating OK KO if the deleting is going OK or KO...javascript but i didn't tested the code under but if i understood the problem this is the way, to test if the row is deleted you can use also mysqli_affected_rows() if 1 ok otherwise KO :

```
        $(".taBort").click(function(){  
            var r = confirm("Do you want to delete the row?");
            if (r == true) {
                var taBortid= $(this).val();
                $.when(deleteRow(taBortid)).then(function(controllo){
                    if (controllo == 'OK'){
                        lista();
                    }
                    if(controllo == 'KO'){
                        alert('Error in delete row');
                    }
                });
            }
        }); 
        function deleteRow(taBortid){
            return $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url : 'delete.php',
                data : { taBortRad:  "Ta bort",          
                         taBortid:   taBortid}
                dataType : 'html',  
            }).then(function(answer){

                if (answer == 'OK'){
                    controllo = 'OK';
                }else{                          
                    controllo = 'KO';        
                }   
                 return controllo;              
            }).fail(function(){
                alert('Error of comunication');
            });             
        }
```

PHP delete.php

```
        if(isset($_POST['taBortRad'])){

            $taBortid=$_POST['taBortid'];
            $conn = new mysqli('YOUR CONNECTION PARAMS');

            $sql = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM parts WHERE id= ?");
            $sql->bind_param('i', $taBortid);
            if ($sql->execute()){
                print 'OK';
            }
            else{
                print 'KO';
            }

        }
```

Update, sorry for my english:
Hy Fredrik, i think that your problem is just the deferred, sinchronous or asynchronous, i try to explain you starting from your question: "but how can I prevent the list to show before the list is updated?"
Your code has a right idea but a wrong syntax i explain why, you want to delete a row and after that the row is deleted reload the table with, i suppose because i didn't see the partList.php, a new select and template buttons and this select and template is in file partList.php is it right?
So at the first time execute ALL the code inside delete.php and only after that the parse is finished to execute the delete.php file, after execute partList.php...is it right?But your code is not doing this.
Well, what you are not considering is in first point the execution time of the parse javascript and execution time of the php parse, when you write $.post...success.. you are doing an ajax call but when the javascript parse enters in the success of the post call???
Not when all the php code is executed but just at the first line of the php delete.php...so when the parse of the php is running the first line in file delete.php in the same time the javascript parse is calling lista() function, to understand us, the javascript parse is calling lista() function before that the php parse is doing the connection and the execution of all the code in delete.php..Because in your code there is nothing that says to the javascript parse WAIT untill i say you to execute partList.php, you need the deferred, or async:false, but async false is deprecated just because we must use deferred objects.
My code is saying(but there is an imperfection also in my code)

```
    $.when(deleteRow(taBortid)).then(function(controllo){...
```

The construct when->then is saying when the promise deletedRow is executed and the function callback is returnig CONTROLLO after do something, in this case the promise is OK KO(or better the promise is deleteRow and function controllo is callback, but try to understand in this way with simple words...Hey javascript i promise you OK or KO ;) ), but when the javascript code receives OK or KO?only after that the parse php has executed ALL the code before to print OK or print KO...In fact in my code there is an imperfection because the

```
      if($sql->execute) print OK
```

Will always executed also if the delete query is not going well for example no row deleted to be precise this will be better

```
    if($sql->execute){
          $numbersRowDeleted = $sql->affected_rows;
          if($numbersRowDeleted >0){
            print 'OK';//ROW IS DELETED
          }
          else{
           print 'NODELETED';//BUT THIS NODELETD MUST BE MANAGED ALSO IN THE JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION AND AFTER IN THE THEN if (answer == 'NODELETED'){controllo no deleted etc...}
          }
    }
```

You can also write

```
      $.when(call1(),call2()...).then(function(controllo1,controllo2...){})
```

The construct when->then has outdated the synchnous and asynchronous calls, writing two calls 1 and 2 all the two calls will be executed in asynnchronous BUT WILL BE MANAGED THE ANSWERS/PROMISE so not need anymore that will be synchronous because the javascript parse will wait the answer for example call 1 answers DOTHIS and call 2 answers DOTHIS2 after do a javascript script, or call1 answers DOANOTHERTHING and call 2 answers DOANOTHERTHING2 then javascript execute another code that you want but all the two php file in call 1 and 2 are asynchronous.
Deferred objects are very importants....
Try my code....Bye
I hope that this explain a little the problem but i tried to explain quickly and not in precise manner for example using also .resolve() method or promise() method...Look also here maybe he explain better than me... :)

http://michaelsoriano.com/working-with-jquerys-ajax-promises-and-deferred-objects/

Comment: Partlist is the phpfile containing the data from the database. The problem is not that the database don´t update. The problem is that I don't always see it immediately, but need to refresh the page. The database is updated but I see "old" data.

Comment: https://youtu.be/VqrIYdwD3s8 shows how it looks, the first time it works and I see the row and the button immediately, next time I need to hit refresh to see the update...